# Group elements followed by a repeating key in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, grouping, python-itertools

How do I group elements in `lst` into sublists that start with `'S'` in Python?

```
lst = ['S', 'one', 'two', 'S', 'three', 'S', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

What I want:

```
[['S', 'one', 'two'], ['S', 'three'], ['S', 'four', 'five', 'six']]
```

edit:

What if now `lst = ['"A"', 'one', 'two', '"B"', 'three', '"C"', 'four', 'five', 'six']`? The first elements are not exactly the same, but have something in common, i.e. the quotation mark.

Comment: what if the first element in not an `'S'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
lst = ['S', 'one', 'two', 'S', 'three', 'S', 'four', 'five', 'six']
res = []
for i in lst:
    if i =="S":
        res.append([i])
    else:
        res[-1].append(i) 
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[['S', 'one', 'two'], ['S', 'three'], ['S', 'four', 'five', 'six']]
```

---

Question Edited.

Use `str.startswith` & `str.endswith`

**Ex:**

```
lst = ['"A"', 'one', 'two', '"B"', 'three', '"C"', 'four', 'five', 'six']
res = []
for i in lst:
    if i.startswith('"') and i.endswith('"'):
        res.append([i])
    else:
        res[-1].append(i) 
print(res)
# --> [['"A"', 'one', 'two'], ['"B"', 'three'], ['"C"', 'four', 'five', 'six']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [['S']+list(g) for k,g in groupby(lst,lambda x:'S' in x) if not k]
[['S', 'one', 'two'], ['S', 'three'], ['S', 'four', 'five', 'six']]
```

Comment: Is there any other work around if I don't want to prepend the hardcoded value back to the sublists?

Comment: I mean you can do this: `def groups(lst, sep):return [[sep]+list(g) for k,g in groupby(lst,lambda x:sep in x) if not k` and then call the function. Meanwhile I am trying to think something better.

Comment: What if the list is now `lst = ['"A"', 'one', 'two', '"B"', 'three', '"C"', 'four', 'five', 'six']`, how do we group them by recognising the quotation mark?